# How to time draw images to the window in d3d8

Tags: directx

I need to be able to draw one image then have it disappear then draw the next image then disappear.
I can draw 1 image on the window but I can not make it disappear and draw image 2.
Also would be great too with some code examples makes it easier for me to read.
Any ideas here is my code.

```
HWND g_hWnd;                                // The application window.
IDirect3D8* g_Dx3D;                     
IDirect3DDevice8* g_d3dDevice;              //The one and only DirectX device
D3DDISPLAYMODE g_d3ddm;                     //Display Mode Capablity.


ID3DXSprite*        g_pSprite;              // The sprite instance
IDirect3DTexture8*  g_pTexture;             // Instance to hold the texture.
D3DXVECTOR2         g_position;             // Position of the sprite.
D3DXVECTOR2         g_velocity;             // Velocity of the sprite.


int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{
// TODO: Place code here.
InitDirect3d();
InitSprite1();

 MSG msg;
 // Main message loop:
 ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(msg) );
 while( msg.message!=WM_QUIT )
 {
    if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
    {
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
    else
        Render();
}

return msg.wParam;

return 0;
}


HRESULT Render()
{


g_d3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0), 1.0f, 0 );

g_d3dDevice->BeginScene();
{
    g_pSprite->Begin();
    {
        g_pSprite->Draw(g_pTexture,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,&g_position,0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    g_pSprite->End();


    g_pSprite->Begin();
    {
        g_pSprite->Draw(g_pTexture,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,&g_position,0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    g_pSprite->End();
}
g_d3dDevice->EndScene();

g_d3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );

return S_OK;
}

*
Initialise the DirectX.
*/
HRESULT InitDirect3d()
{
do
{
    if(FAILED(InitWindow()))
    {
        break;
    }

    g_Dx3D = Direct3DCreate8( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

    if(g_Dx3D == NULL)
    {
        break;
    }

    if( FAILED( g_Dx3D->GetAdapterDisplayMode( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &g_d3ddm ) ) )
    {
        break;
    }

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; 
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );
    d3dpp.Windowed   = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = g_d3ddm.Format;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = g_hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = WINDOW_HEIGHT;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    

    if( FAILED( g_Dx3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, g_hWnd,
                                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                                      &d3dpp, &g_d3dDevice ) ) )
    {
        break;
    }
    return S_OK;
} while(false);

return E_FAIL;
}


/*
Create the window that we will use to render the image.
*/
HRESULT InitWindow()
{
WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_CLASSDC, WndProc, 0L, 0L, 
              GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
              "D3D Tutorial", NULL };
RegisterClassEx( &wc );

DWORD dwFrameWidth    = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSIZEFRAME );
DWORD dwFrameHeight   = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSIZEFRAME );
DWORD dwMenuHeight    = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYMENU );
DWORD dwCaptionHeight = GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION );
DWORD dwWindowWidth   = WINDOW_WIDTH  + dwFrameWidth * 2;
DWORD dwWindowHeight  = WINDOW_HEIGHT + dwFrameHeight * 2 + 
                        dwMenuHeight + dwCaptionHeight;
// Create the application's window.
g_hWnd = CreateWindow( "D3D Tutorial", 
                          "test", 
                          
WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_CAPTION|WS_SYSMENU|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_VISIBLE, 
                          CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, dwWindowWidth, dwWindowHeight,
                          GetDesktopWindow(), 
                          NULL, 
                          wc.hInstance, 
                          NULL );

if(g_hWnd == NULL)
{
    return(E_FAIL);
}

ShowWindow(g_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);

return(S_OK);

}


/*
 Initialise the sprite.
 */
 HRESULT InitSprite1()
 {
 HRESULT logo1;

 logo1 = D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(g_d3dDevice,"backgorund.jpeg",&g_pTexture);

 g_position.x = 10;
 g_position.y = 10;

logo1 = D3DXCreateSprite(g_d3dDevice,&g_pSprite); 

return logo1;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message) 
{
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using an extremely out-dated API like DirectX 8 instead of at least DirectX 11? (Which is still supported and actively updated even on Windows 10).

Comment: I'm building old software that requires this out-dated API of DirectX 8